# jQuery UI Dialog won't open upon <select> click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, opencart, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to open the jQuery UI Dialog box when a user clicks on a select option as such:

```
<select id="js-test" name="product_combination[<?php echo $combination_row; ?>][product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id]"  > 
   <?php 
      foreach($list_of_colours as $acolour){
   ?>

<option value="<?php echo $acolour['id']; ?>" 
   id="<?php echo $acolour['id']; ?>"
   <?php 
    if($acolour['id'] == $product_combination['product_colour_sizes_option_value_colour_id']){ 
   ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> >
   <?php echo $acolour['name'] ?>
</option>
   <?php } ?>
</select>
```

My dialog box is afew lines above this:

```
<!-- Start Dialog Box Here -->
  <div id="myDialog" title="Size Selection">
     <div class="box" style="display:none;">
        I am Dailog
     </div>
  </div>
<!-- /end Dialog Box -->
```

And my jQuery code is in an external file as such:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//$("#myDialog").dialog({autoOpen:false});

$("#myDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen:false,
    height:300,
    width:400,
    modal: true
});

$("#js-test").click(function(){
    $("#myDialog").dialog("open");
    var selection = $('#js-test').find(':selected').text();
    console.log(selection);

  });
});
```

My console logs get display in the console log as i would expect them to when my select options are clicked. But my dialog box remains a no show. Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i needed to place my dialog box after my call! Resolved.